# Python DataFrame - create index from row values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to alter a python / pandas dataframe:

Current structure of DataFrame:

|  | QTY | EUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| timestamp | 1610116649 | 1610116649 |
| transactions | 12 | 30 |

Target structure:

| timestamp | QTY | EUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1610114340 | 12 | 30 |

My Code:
`target = pd.pivot(current, index='timestamp', columns=['QTY', 'EUR'])`

Error message:

`KeyError: "None of ['timestamp'] are in the columns"`

I also tried an alternative current structure after a transpose:

|  | timestamp | transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QTY | 1610114340 | 12 |
| EUR | 1610114340 | 30 |

My Code :
`target = pd.pivot(current, index='timestamp', columns=['QTY', 'EUR'])`

Error message:

`None of ['QTY', 'EUR'] are in the columns`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. I would suggest including the output of ```current.head()```  or even better, the constructor of an example data frame. Otherwise, I would suggest looking at the examples in the documentation of ```pd.pivot``` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to transpose the first data frame and then transform it by pivoting.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
QTY EUR
timestamp 1610116649 1610116649
transactions 12 30
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df = df.T
pd.pivot(df, index='timestamp', columns='index', values='transactions')

index   EUR     QTY
timestamp       
1610116649  30  12
```

Comment: Hi r-beginners, thanks for your suggestion. As I have a dataframe with the described structure and am not starting from an csv-import, your first line of coe does not apply and injecting only the subsequent lines did not work, either.

Comment: I'm just using `pd.read_cvs()` to dataframe the data you presented. Is the structure of the data different? You should be able to use it from `df = df.T`.

Comment: Hi, r-beginners. I'm working with a dataframe that is based on a json response job. And that is also the key to the problem: I had to normalise the json data before creating a dataframe because normalising creates the index which was missing initally. And with index, the transpose and pivot routines yielded the desired output.

Comment: I'm glad I got the desired output. Please accept my response.